# Get the sum of fields from a mysql table using a query

Tags: mysql

i have the following table in my databse..

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client` (
  `CARD_NO` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `F_NAME` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `L_NAME` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `SEX` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `DOB` date NOT NULL,
  `SUBCITY` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `KEBELE` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `HOUSE_NO` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `TEL_NO` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REGION_NO` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CARD_NO`),
  KEY `REGION_NO` (`REGION_NO`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `client`
--

INSERT INTO `client` (`CARD_NO`, `F_NAME`, `L_NAME`, `SEX`, `DOB`, `SUBCITY`, `KEBELE`, `HOUSE_NO`, `TEL_NO`, `REGION_NO`) VALUES
('1', '', '', 'male', '0000-00-00', '', '', '', NULL, '01'),
('2', '', '', 'male', '0000-00-00', '', '', '', NULL, '02'),
('3', '', '', 'femal', '0000-00-00', '', '', '', NULL, '03'),
('4', '', '', 'femal', '0000-00-00', '', '', '', NULL, '04'),
('5', '', '', 'male', '0000-00-00', '', '', '', NULL, '05'),
('6', '', '', 'male', '0000-00-00', '', '', '', NULL, '05');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `non_pregnant`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `non_pregnant` (
  `VCT_CODE` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `CARD_NO` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RISK_OF_HIV` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `PURPOSE` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`VCT_CODE`),
  KEY `CARD_NO` (`CARD_NO`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `non_pregnant`
--

INSERT INTO `non_pregnant` (`VCT_CODE`, `CARD_NO`, `RISK_OF_HIV`, `PURPOSE`) VALUES
('1', '1', '', ''),
('2', '2', '', ''),
('3', '3', '', ''),
('4', '4', '', ''),
('5', '5', '', ''),
('6', '6', '', '');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `non_pregnant_vct`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `non_pregnant_vct` (
  `VCT_CODE` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DATE_TESTED` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `TB_RESULT` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `HIV_RESULT` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `STD_RESULT` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`VCT_CODE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `non_pregnant_vct`
--

INSERT INTO `non_pregnant_vct` (`VCT_CODE`, `DATE_TESTED`, `TB_RESULT`, `HIV_RESULT`, `STD_RESULT`) VALUES
('1', NULL, '', 'pos', ''),
('2', NULL, '', 'pos', ''),
('3', NULL, '', 'neg', ''),
('4', NULL, '', 'neg', ''),
('5', NULL, '', 'neg', ''),
('6', NULL, '', 'pos', '');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `region`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `region` (
  `REGION_NO` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `REGION_NAME` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`REGION_NO`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `region`
--

INSERT INTO `region` (`REGION_NO`, `REGION_NAME`) VALUES
('01', 'washington'),
('02', 'newyork'),
('03', 'london'),
('04', 'paris'),
('05', 'burlin');
```

here is what i want as output..

Region
    Female
    Male
    Total
    
  
    Test
    Positive
    Test
    Positive
    Test
    Positive

and this is the query i tried to figure it out but still wrong..

```
SELECT r.region_name, c.sex = 'male' as counting, c.sex = 'femal' as counting, v.hiv_result = 'pos' as MalePos from region r
left join client c
on c.region_no = r.region_no
left join non_pregnant p
on c.card_no = p.card_no
left join non_pregnant_vct v
on p.vct_code = v.vct_code
group by c.region_no;
```

Comment: what's the error message you get?

Comment: What output are you getting?  How does it compare to what should be right?  You might want to elaborate and give us some help here.

Comment: Out of curiousity, is that extra varchar for gender really that expensive? ("femal" just looks strange)

Comment: @sase, please tell us what you *want* in each column of the output, not just the column names.

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the output you want is breathtakingly unclear, but I'll give it a shot.  Try this:

```
SELECT
    r.region_name,
    SUM(c.sex = 'male') as NMale,
    SUM(c.sex = 'femal') as NFemale,
    SUM(v.hiv_result = 'pos') as TotalPos,
    SUM(c.sex = 'male' AND v.hiv_result = 'pos') as MalePos,
    SUM(c.sex = 'femal' AND v.hiv_result = 'pos') as FemalePos
FROM region r
LEFT JOIN client c ON c.region_no = r.region_no
LEFT JOIN non_pregnant p ON c.card_no = p.card_no
LEFT JOIN non_pregnant_vct v ON p.vct_code = v.vct_code
GROUP BY c.region_no
```

Comment: thanks, man...i appriciate ur answer...i am almost make it ur code a bit of change and it works perfect....thanks alot.